# SQL Remove unwanted duplicate lines

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016, how can I query the result set below to omit RowIDs 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 16, 18, 19, 20, 23 and 24?

These rows are displaying the same information already shown in other rows.

| RowID | OrganisationURN | OrganisationName | ParticipantURN | ParticipantName | amount | fiscalyear | fiscalperiod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | -120.74 | 2009 | March |
| 2 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | -120.74 | 2009 | March |
| 3 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | December |
| 4 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | October |
| 5 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | December |
| 6 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | October |
| 7 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 12.24 | 2009 | October |
| 8 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 12.24 | 2009 | October |
| 9 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 30 | 2009 | March |
| 10 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 30 | 2009 | March |
| 11 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | February |
| 12 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | March |
| 13 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | February |
| 14 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | March |
| 15 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 55.65 | 2009 | October |
| 16 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 55.65 | 2009 | October |
| 17 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 90 | 2009 | December |
| 18 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 90 | 2009 | December |
| 19 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | December |
| 20 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | March |
| 21 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | December |
| 22 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | March |
| 23 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | December |
| 24 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | March |
| 25 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | December |
| 26 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | March |

I tried:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        organisationurn,
        organisationname,
        contacturn,
        contactname,
        amount,
        fiscalyear,
        fiscalperiod,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY organisationurn
                           ORDER BY organisationname ASC) RN
    FROM 
        #data
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN <> 1;
```

but it just returns the same output.

What I want is this:

| RowID | OrganisationURN | OrganisationName | ParticipantURN | ParticipantName | amount | fiscalyear | fiscalperiod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | -120.74 | 2009 | March |
| 2 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | -120.74 | 2009 | March |
| 3 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | December |
| 4 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 10 | 2009 | October |
| 7 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 12.24 | 2009 | October |
| 9 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 30 | 2009 | March |
| 13 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | February |
| 14 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 50 | 2009 | March |
| 15 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 55.65 | 2009 | October |
| 17 | 1 | FakeGroup Plc | 7 | Mr John Doe | 90 | 2009 | December |
| 21 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | December |
| 22 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 100 | 2009 | March |
| 25 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | December |
| 26 | 2 | Ladybug (Whole Company) | 7 | Mr John Doe | 120.74 | 2009 | March |

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2016?

I have added a RowID column which isnt part of the data for reference purposes to this question only

Comment: Those rows you noted as duplicates all looked to have distinct values, mostly in the fiscalperiod column.

Comment: Try `= 1` rather than `<> 1`

Comment: @dogyog - duplicate rowIDs 5 and 6 are duplicates of 3 and 4 in everything but organisationName. What's throwing off the data is the OrganisationName column. The table is based on John Doe and any related companies John has worked with. John has worked with Fakegroup and Ladybug only. So it appears the table was constructed to show the monies John has raised on his own while still trying to show the companies John has worked with. relationship and monies raised are mutually exclusive. 

I can easily output the unique organisationName and monies separately but not together in the same result

Comment: @shawnt00 - tried ```=1``` and gives me 2 rows only - RowIDs 1 and 2

Comment: Why isn't 2 considered to be a "dup" of 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can group by all of your columns, which will return only unique rows.  Though, as it's been pointed those rows *are* unique.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
GROUP BY RowID, OrganisationURN, OrganisationName, ParticipantURN, ParticipantName, amount, fiscalyear, fiscalperiod
```

Comment: I have added a RowID column which isnt part of the data for reference purposes to this question only. I edited the question to clarify this. 

```SELECT``` with ```GROUP BY``` gives the same output with duplicates. OrganisationName column is throwing off the data because OrganisationName isnt related to the amount, fiscalperiod, and fiscalyear